# How to get the number of rows in column A starting from a certain cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get the number of non-empty rows in Column A starting from A3 for example. How do i do it?

What I have tried:

```
Dim row as integer
row = Sheets("Part2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

But it calculates all the rows in columnA. Want it to start it from A3.

Need some guidance.

Comment: So you want, for example, the number of rows from A3 to the last row, no matter if they're filled or not? The example you gave doesn't calculate all the rows in A, it gives you the row of the last filled cell in A.

Comment: can you clarify please? you want number of non empty rows starting from A3? or number of rows from A3 to the last row?

Comment: Yes. I want the number of non empty rows starting from A3. edited the question as well.

Comment: Why not just take `row - 3`?

Comment: row is a reserved word !! You should not use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For counting non empty cells starting from `A3` use this one:

```
Dim cntRows As Long
With Sheets("Part2")
    cntRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) - WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A1:A2"))
End With
```

also note, that I'm using `Long` type for `cntRows` (since max value of `Integer` is only `32768`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("a3:a" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

I tried first another formula using `Range("a3:a" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count` being quite sure it was the best path, but strangely that gives me an error...

Comment: your formula doesn't take into account cells with formulas.. i.e. if `A4` contains `=IF(B1,1,2)`